# Can you prove a theorem by proving it’s undecidable? (Numberphile question)

Tags: incompleteness, provability, decidability

Numberphile posted a vid on 5-31-17 about Godel’s Incompleteness Theorem.  Near the end of the vid, the professor argues that proving that the Riemann Hypothesis is undecidable would PROVE the Riemann Hypothesis.

His logic, as I understand it, that a RH counter-example would render the problem decidable, therefore if the RH is undecidable no counter-example can exist.

https://youtu.be/O4ndIDcDSGc?t=713

This an Oxford math prof, so I'm sure he knows what he’s doing, but deciding something by proving it can’t be decided seems like a wee contradiction to me.  Can anyone clear this up?

Comment: There have been several similar questions about this video recently...

Comment: I didn't watch the video, but take anything stated on a Numberphile video with a grain of salt.

Comment: @Aweygan  Hey, I would never just accept something I heard from an Oxford professor until I got confirmation from Stack Exchange!

Comment: @Jerry Guem savage

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  Yes, you're right this is a duplicate of that question.  I didn't spot that when I searched because his question title isn't very illuminating.  I left a comment suggesting he change that.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm actually not sure it's a duplicate - that question is about the logical form of RH (or rather, its equivalent formulation in terms of natural numbers) which makes it different from Goldbach ($\Pi_1$ versus $\Pi_2$), whereas this question (I think) is about the tension between undecidability and provability in general.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  Thanks for the backup, but that other question actually is a long-winded super-set of this question.  He covers a number of topics, but this one was in there.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305838/if-the-collatz-conjecture-is-unsolvable-is-it-true

Answer (score 4):

**I haven't had a chance to watch the video, but the argument you've described makes an important error which is incidental to this question; I'll treat this error below.**

There's a subtlety here, which crops up all the time in logic or whenever we're doing logic-y things: *what system are we working in*?

Whenever you use words like "provable," "undecidable," or similar, you're always hiding an important bit of context; provability only makes sense *with respect to some system of axioms*. Goedel's incompleteness theorem is a great example of this: given an appropriate theory $T$, we find a sentence $p$ and prove "$p$ is true but $T$ doesn't prove $p$" - but we prove this in a theory *stronger than $T$ itself*, so this isn't a contradiction.

The exact same thing is going on here. We have some appropriate (in particular, sufficiently strong) theory $T$, and some stronger theory $S$. Suppose $S$ proves that $T$ doesn't disprove RH; there are two relevant facts kicking around here:

- If $T$ doesn't disprove RH, then RH is true. (This is provable in $T$ itself.)
- $T$ doesn't disprove RH. (This is provable in $S$, but not necessarily in $T$.)

In order to conclude "RH is true," we need *both* of these facts; $S$ has them, but $T$ doesn't necessarily. So we can think of this as a kind of meta-reasoning - we're using two different kinds of provability here ($S$-provability and $T$-provability), and our argument only gives us a proof of RH in the *first* sense.

---

In fact, we can *prove* (again, in a stronger theory than $T$ :P) that $T$ doesn't prove that it doesn't disprove RH (whew, that's a mouthful!). This is because if $T$ is inconsistent, then it disproves *everything*; put another way, if $T$ doesn't disprove something, then $T$ is consistent. $T$ can prove this if $T$ is sufficiently powerful, so if $T$ proved "I don't disprove RH" then $T$ would prove "I am consistent," and this can't happen as long as $T$ is consistent by Goedel's second incompleteness theorem. So the theory $T+Con(T)$, which is stronger than $T$, proves "$T$ doesn't prove that $T$ doesn't disprove RH" (and of course we can replace RH with *anything* here).

---

OK, now the error:

Suppose there was a counterexample to RH. This counterexample is some complex number $z$. But there are uncountably many complex numbers, and only countably many expressions in the language of our theory; so most complex numbers can't be defined in the language we're working in! This means that for most complex numbers $z$, our theory $T$ can't even *express* the statement "$z$ is a counterexample to RH," let alone *prove* it. And now we have a problem: *what if there are counterexamples to RH, but they're all undefinable?*

So the argument there is really missing something important. This can, however, be fixed: it turns out that RH is [equivalent to an appropriate statement about natural numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31846/is-the-riemann-hypothesis-equivalent-to-a-pi-1-sentence/172478), such that our theory $T$ can verify a counterexample to it if one exists.

But this is a really important point, and it's annoying to see it glossed over!

Comment: That's why I prefer such argumentation using Goldbach instead of RH ... :)

Comment: I would call this a flaw in the argument rather than an error.  The statement "$z$ is a counterexample to RH" may not be expressible, but the statement "there is a counterexample to RH in the open rectangle $q_1 < x < q_2$, $q_3 < y < q_4$" certainly is expressible for rational $q_i$, and such statements are decidable (not sure if this would be true for an arbitrary analytic function, but we know enough about how to count zeros of $zeta$ for this to work).